# How Do I Pass a CImg Image Object from C++/CLI to C#

Tags: c#, c++, bitmap, c++-cli, cimg

I have some C++/CLI code that creates a simple CImg image and draws a circle on it. I want to pass it to C#, but I'm not sure how. I thought of using a byte array to pass it to C#, but I can't get the length of the array, which is needed for any conversion from byte* to byte[] or for passing into the unmanaged memory stream. I've tried using strlen, but that just returns 0.

Here is my C++ code:

```
unsigned char* calculateFrame::ReadImage() {
    CImg<unsigned char> testImage(1920, 1080, 1, 3, 0);
    const unsigned char white[3] = { 255,255,255 };
    testImage.draw_circle(256, 256, 200, white, 1.0f, ~0U);
    testImage.draw_point(500, 500, white, 255);

    unsigned char* charArray = (unsigned char*)testImage;
    return charArray;
}
```

C# code:

```
Bitmap testBmp;

        using(var test = new FrameCalculator.calculateFrame())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test.calculateOneFrame(3));
            unsafe
            {
                byte* imageArray = test.ReadImage();
                using(var ms = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(imageArray , /* length of byte* (unknown) */))
                {
                    testBmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                }
            }
        }
```

If you have any tricks to get around unsafe code without sacrificing performance, that would be nice, but I'm not opposed to using unsafe code if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding that in the future, I would need a frame buffer, which necessitated writing the frames to the disk, so that they weren't lost in a restart.

Anyways, my solution was to write the image to disk as a .BMP and access it using Image.FromFile in C#. This isn't a great way to do this in most cases, because it adds a lot of overhead, but it made sense in my program.